# Android Studio Splash screen is looping indefinitely and will not stop

Tags: android, loops, screen, splash-screen

I'm really new to coding and have almost no idea what I'm doing.

I need to get this splash screen to work but it keeps looping infinitely back between the splash screen and mainactivity and I have no idea why, I took the code off some YouTube video and the video had no explanation too so I'm stuck.

This is the code for mainactivity:

```
package sg.edu.tp.project1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;
private ImageButton Search01;
private ImageButton Mymusic;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Search01 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Search);
    Mymusic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Mymusic);


        }
{ new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }



},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
public void gotoSearchpage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, searchpage.class);
    this.startActivity ( intent );
}
public void gotoMymusic(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myMusic.class);
    this.startActivity ( intent );

}
public void gotoPlaylist(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, playlist.class);
    this.startActivity ( intent );
} }
```

and this is the code for the splash screen:

```
package sg.edu.tp.project1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
{ new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, 
MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }



},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}


}
```

Comment: start intent without using handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all... use AsyncTask in `Splash screen` it is best practice to do background initialization and checks.

Second you don't need handler in `MainActivity`.

remove this code from MainActivity... it is redirecting u to **HomeActivity**.

```
{ new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }



},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

**and change your HomeActivity(Splash) like this..**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    new Loader().execute();

}


    private class Loader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss();

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            HomeActivity.this.finish();

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: i tried that but now it just stays on the splash screen

Comment: i honestly have no idea what that means, can you show me which part of the code to change?

Comment: pleasure to help.. happy coding :)